# MVC, cannot return to the previous URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on some legacy code.
I have a form which I edit some data and when I click save, if successful I want to return to the previous form.
So my controller methods are;

```
public ActionResult Edit(int callDiaryId)
        {
            ViewBag.PreviousUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
            var callDiary = this.SCDCallDiaryRepository.Get(callDiaryId);
            return this.View("Edit", new DiaryItemViewModel(callDiary));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateOnlyIncomingValuesAttribute]
        public ActionResult Edit(DiaryItemViewModel item, string previousUrl)
        {
            var callDiary = this.SCDCallDiaryRepository.Get(item.SCD_CallDiaryId);
            callDiary.Comments = item.Comments;
            callDiary.ContractId = item.ContractId;
            var opStatus = this.SCDCallDiaryRepository.Update(callDiary);
            if (opStatus.Status)
            {
                this.TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Details updated successfully.".MessageTime();
                return RedirectToAction(previousUrl);
            }

            this.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Details NOT updated.".MessageTime();
            ViewBag.PreviousUrl = previousUrl;
            return this.View(new DiaryItemViewModel(callDiary));
        }
```

and the incoming value of previousUrl is

```
http://localhost:58384/LogDiary/Comments?companyId=11033
```

This works perfectly for my back button.
But after my RedirectToAction command is performed, the Bad Request error that I get is because the Url it is showing is;

```
http://localhost:58384/LogDiary/http%3a/localhost%3a58384/LogDiary/Comments%3fcompanyId%3d11033
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.
Instead of using RedirectToAction, I am now using Redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in the Controller of my App to return the user to the previous page

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
    var userId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var viewModel = this._userService.ChangePasswordViewModelForUser(userId);

    viewModel.PreviousPage = this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;

    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

If I need to use it in a button

```
<a href="@HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer" class="btn btn-primary">@Resource.Button_Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return to the previous form by doing the below code

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateOnlyIncomingValuesAttribute]
        public ActionResult Edit(DiaryItemViewModel item)
        {
            ..your other code..
            return View(item);
        }
```

it will return to the `Edit` page along with the entered data
hope this helps